# The connection with remote endpoint was terminated error in azure service fabric

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I am getting the following error :

```
Unable to start debugging 'path.exe'
The connection with remote endpoint was terminated.
```

I am running a service fabric solution with asp.net core console app and webApi projects on VS2017.

Comment: See the following which might help: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/217242/debugger-failed-with-the-remote-endpoint-was-termi.html

Comment: Have tried those steps on this page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/unable-to-connect-to-the-microsoft-visual-studio-remote-debugging-monitor

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Micah_MSFT It was the same issue as discussed in the link!

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same error in visual studio 2017 and the problem solved when run the visual studio as administrator I wish this help someone facing the same problem